# Getting rid of escape characters in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

I've got a string containing values such as `"hello world\' hello world\'"` and I'd like to get rid of the escape characters (the backslashes.)

I've tried the following code:

```
str_replace("\\", "", $data);
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you want to do in the first place?

Comment: `str_replace` returns the result. Are you assigning it to anything?

Comment: I bet [the fine php manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) describing the behavior @takteek mentions works. Always consult the PHP documentation before asking why something doesn't work or you'll get A-holes like me yelling at you :)

Comment: Wow sorry that was a fail on my part wasn't assigning it to a variable duhh! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want to do is to get rid of backslashes, then there's a very handy PHP function that accomplishes just that

```
$var = stripslashes($var);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using $var as the last parameter in str_replace() instead of $data, it should work fine.

```
$var = "hello world\' hello world\'";
echo $var . "<br />";
echo str_replace("\\", "", $var) . "<br />";
```

Output:

```
hello world\' hello world\'
hello world' hello world'
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work great for you you were not referencing the variable $var correctly in php replace subject parameter also assuming you need to replace the \' you were putting \ which searches for it hence nothing was found to be replaced hope this helps

```
$var = "hello world\' hello world\'";

echo str_replace("\'","",$var);
```